# Rails changing a long if/else statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I'm trying to put in dynamic anchor tags for accessibility. Based on the url the anchor tag is put at the top under the body. I ended up doing something like this in the view:

```
<body>
 <div class="skip">
  <%= yield :upper_body%>
  <%= anchor_update %>
  <a href="/"> Navigation - Home </a>
 </div>
</body>
```

My anchor_update method has the following if/else mess that I'd like to clean up:

```
def anchor_update
 url = request.original_url
 if url.include?('services')
   content_tag(:a, "Skip to Services Content", :href => '#services')
 elsif url.include?('about')
   content_tag(:a, "Skip to About", :href => '#about-content')
 elsif url.include?('core-values')
   content_tag(:a, "Skip to Core Values Content", :href => '#core-values')
 elsif url.include?('condition')
  content_tag(:a, "Skip to Condition Content", :href => '#condition-content')
 elsif url.include?('top')
  content_tag(:a, "Skip to Top Content", :href => '#top-content')
 else
   '¯\_(ツ)_/¯'
end
end
```

EDIT: Originally I had no idea how to safely escape the statement. return works. But it's a messy solution with if/elsif. So I'm trying to figure out if there's a cleaner solution.

Additional EDIT:
We're currently using a CMS that allows the users to generate new pages that will use a template that we designed for them called two_pane and there are like 20 of these thus the method that tries to hit every page.

Comment: Out of curiosity: what is the CMS in question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get rid of long if-elseif-else statement you could use `case` with regexp:

```
def anchor_update
  url = request.original_url
  case url
  when /services/
    content_tag(:a, "Skip to Services Content", href: '#services')
  when /about/
    content_tag(:a, "Skip to About", href: '#about-content')
  when /core-values/
    content_tag(:a, "Skip to Core Values Content", href: '#core-values')
  when /condition/
    content_tag(:a, "Skip to Condition Content", href: '#condition-content')
  when /top/
    content_tag(:a, "Skip to Top Content", href: '#top-content')
  else
    '¯\_(ツ)_/¯'
  end
end
```

Comment: Probably more of a regexp question but how would you hit the sub? So for example if the website ended with www.something.com/about/meet-joe? /about/ hits about so how would you handle those that have additional?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by 'sub' and 'additional'.

Comment: Please see this [link](https://www.rubyguides.com/2015/10/ruby-case/), 'Ruby Case & Regex' section. They covered how `case` can be used with regexp

Comment: So hitting the further part of the url. In the case of my example: www.something.com/about/meet-joe and your answer of doing cases with regexp it would actually show the content_tag information on both the about page and then the /about/meet-joe page.

Comment: The `/about/` condition will match both "www.something.com/about/meet-joe" and "www.something.com/about/" URLs. If you want to match last URL only, you could use `/about[\/]?\z/` condition, that will check URL ending too

Answer (score 3):

The case answer is a good start. But you could just be using link_to instead of content_tag to cleanup all that duplication.

```
link_to("Skip to Services Content",'#services')

link_to("Skip to About", '#about-content')
```

Etc.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an actual answer.